# Why do 2 Object have diff hash codes, but 2 String have the same hash codes in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, hash, hashmap

```
class A{
    int a;
    A(){
        this.a = 100;
    }
}
//in main, we have:
A a = new A(), b = new A();
//and
String str0 = "123", str1 = "123";
```

Why do the hash codes of str0 and str1 are the same, but not a and b?

Comment: str0 and str1 point to same reference in the StringPool , whereas 'a' and 'b' point to different references in memory since 'new' keyword is used.

Comment: It has nothing to do with String interning.

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking It does. Even if `String` *didn't* override `hashCode`, the OP would get the same result because `str1` and `str2` are references to the same object, whereas `a` and `b` aren't.

Comment: You are mixing concepts. hashCode() has to return the same value if the objects are equal, that's it. Interning does not matter here as the objects are equal anyway.

Comment: @pbabcdef But it *does* override `hashCode,` which is what makes interning irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

Because `String` *overrides* `Object.hashCode()` while your class doesn't.

What this means is that the `String` class has a specific implementation of `hashCode()` that will calculate a hash based on the `String` value. So for two strings with the same value, the hash code will be the same.

When you create a new class, `A`, for example, if you do not provide your own implementation for `hashCode()` it will use the default implementation from class `Object`. The default implementation can only guarantee that the hash codes will be the same if they come from **exactly the same instance**.

The methods `Objects.hash()` (for multiple values) and `Objects.hashCode()` (for a single value) make it easier to implement `hashCode()` in your own classes. For example:

```
class A{
    int a;

    A() {
        this.a = 100;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(a);
    }
}
```

Note that if the values of the attributes used to create the hash change at some point, the result of `hashCode()` will probably change too.

Answer (score 2):

Because the implementation of `hashCode()` in `java.lang.String` class is overridden.

In order to be able to use `String`s in collections, the implementation has to be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Because the hashCode implementation for String has been built to always return the same hash code for the the same collection of chars in a given order. Whereas Object.hashCode() treats ever object as unique. If you want to know if two Strings are different object then you could Objects.hashCode(someString)

```
/**
 * Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a
 * {@code String} object is computed as
 * <blockquote><pre>
 * s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
 * </pre></blockquote>
 * using {@code int} arithmetic, where {@code s[i]} is the
 * <i>i</i>th character of the string, {@code n} is the length of
 * the string, and {@code ^} indicates exponentiation.
 * (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)
 *
 * @return  a hash code value for this object.
 */
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```